# How to store multiple value of printf in a variable?

Tags: c

The program must accept an integer N with even number of digits as the input.
The program must reverse every two digits in N and print the modified N as the output.

Boundary Condition(s): 10 <= N < 10^16
Input Format: The first line contains N.
Output Format: The first line contains the modified N.

Example Input/Output 1:
Input: 214587
Output: 125478

Explanation: The first two digits are 2 and 1 which are reversed as 1 and 2. The second two digits are 4 and 5 which are reversed as 5 and 4. The third two digits are 8 and 7 which are reversed as 7 and 8.

Example Input/Output 2:
Input: 504786
Output: 57468

I have proceeded in a logic of printing the values inside a while loop by printing `b/10` and `b%10;` where the output should be reversed and I am stuck in it, please help in my logic how to proceed further thank you.

```
scanf("%d",&a);
while(a>0) {
    b=a%100;
    printf("%d%d",b/10,b%10);
    a=a/100;
}
```

Comment: What should happen `if (!(floor(log10(input)) % 2))`?

Comment: I would first receive the input as a string (`fgets()`), and then manipulate it still as a string, instead of a number.

Comment: Use recursion; after stripping off the last two digits with `b = a % 100;`, if `a / 100 > 0`, call the function recursively with `a / 100` to do the printing of the significant digits, then work on `b` before returning.  You can also report odd numbers of digits if `a / 100` is between 1 and 9.  You might get leading zeros if you have a number such as 1040.

Comment: Also, for a number with 16 decimal digits, you'll need to use `long long` or `unsigned long long` (or perhaps `int64_t` or  `uint64_t` and `<inttypes.h>`).

Comment: I also think you should use `printf("%d%d", b % 10, b / 10);` to reverse the digits.  It looks like you're printing them in the same order as they appear in the original number.

Answer (score 0):

As I noted in three comments ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56092561/how-to-store-multiple-value-of-printf-in-a-variable#comment98821398_56092561), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56092561/how-to-store-multiple-value-of-printf-in-a-variable#comment98821422_56092561), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56092561/how-to-store-multiple-value-of-printf-in-a-variable#comment98821591_56092561)), I think you need to use recursion, and some care.  Here is code that works, and a test harness (which is bigger than the code being tested) demonstrating that it works:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static bool reverse_digit_pairs(uint64_t value)
{
    uint64_t b = value % 100;
    uint64_t v = value / 100;

    if ((v > 0 && v < 10) || (v == 0 && b < 10))
        return false;

    int t = b / 10;     // tens
    int u = b % 10;     // units
    bool ok = true;
    if (v >= 10)
        ok = reverse_digit_pairs(v);
    if (ok)
    {
        if (u == 0 && v == 0)
            printf("%d", t);
        else
            printf("%d%d", u, t);
    }
    return ok;
}

static void test_reverse_digit_pairs(uint64_t v)
{
    printf("V: %20" PRIu64 " = ", v);
    if (!reverse_digit_pairs(v))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Odd number of digits in %" PRIu64 "\n", v);
        printf("bogus input");
    }
    putchar('\n');
    fflush(0);   // Ensure standard output (and standard error) are flushed.
}

int main(void)
{
    test_reverse_digit_pairs(UINT64_C(214587));             // 125478 per question
    test_reverse_digit_pairs(UINT64_C(504786));             // 57468  per question
    test_reverse_digit_pairs(UINT64_C(5047000086));         // Pairs of zeros
    test_reverse_digit_pairs(UINT64_C(5047900086));         // Pair of zeros
    test_reverse_digit_pairs(UINT64_C(1234567890123456));   // 16 digits
    test_reverse_digit_pairs(UINT64_MAX);                   // 20 digits
    test_reverse_digit_pairs(UINT64_C(123456789012345));    // Odd digits - failure
    test_reverse_digit_pairs(UINT64_C(0));                  // Odd digits - failure
    test_reverse_digit_pairs(UINT64_C(1));                  // Odd digits - failure
    test_reverse_digit_pairs(UINT64_C(9));                  // Odd digits - failure
    test_reverse_digit_pairs(UINT64_C(10));                 // 2 digits
    test_reverse_digit_pairs(UINT64_C(99));                 // 2 digits
    test_reverse_digit_pairs(UINT64_C(100));                // Odd digits - failure
    test_reverse_digit_pairs(UINT64_C(999));                // Odd digits - failure
    test_reverse_digit_pairs(UINT64_C(1000));               // 4 digits
    test_reverse_digit_pairs(UINT64_C(1098));               // 4 digits
    test_reverse_digit_pairs(UINT64_C(1234));               // 4 digits
    return 0;
}
```

The output I get from it is:

```
V:               214587 = 125478
V:               504786 = 57468
V:           5047000086 = 574000068
V:           5047900086 = 574090068
V:     1234567890123456 = 2143658709214365
V: 18446744073709551615 = 81447644707390556151
Odd number of digits in 123456789012345
V:      123456789012345 = bogus input
Odd number of digits in 0
V:                    0 = bogus input
Odd number of digits in 1
V:                    1 = bogus input
Odd number of digits in 9
V:                    9 = bogus input
V:                   10 = 1
V:                   99 = 99
Odd number of digits in 100
V:                  100 = bogus input
Odd number of digits in 999
V:                  999 = bogus input
V:                 1000 = 100
V:                 1098 = 189
V:                 1234 = 2143
```

The test cases for the numbers with 1 to 4 digits were necessary to flush out some issues.  I'm not completely happy with the first condition in `reverse_digit_pairs()`, but I didn't get the output I think is required when I tried some simplifications.