# Swapping alternate digits of a number

Tags: c

I am working with some of the problems that are given under hackerrank modules. The question is about swapping the alternate digits of the given number.

I have tried my logic in C. It worked for most of the test cases but couldn't crack some corner case which i am unable to check with. Here is what i have tried.

```
int main() {
    int n,i,j;
    char a[20];
    scanf("%s",a);
    n=strlen(a);
    if(n==1){
        printf("%s",a);
    }
    else{
        for(i=0,j=i+1;i<n-1 && j<n;i=i+2,j=j+2){
            a[i]^=a[j]^=a[i]^=a[j];
        }
        printf("%s",a);   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am not able to visualize the test cases provided by the module owner as i don't have access to them. These were some of the practice problems given in my college for placement preparation. So i don't have access to the test cases and that's why am not able to provide with those failing test cases and their outputs.  Someone please help me with what i had gone wrong in the logic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add these things to the question: A clear definition of the task to be performed, a test case for which an incorrect answer is produced, the output of the incorrect case, and the desired output of the case. Note: I understand “I am not able to visualize the test cases provided by the module owner” may mean you do not have easy access to the data of a failing test case. You should at least attempt to construct one or give whatever information you do have, such as the complete output from the online judge, as well as identification for the problem (URL, problem number, something).

Comment: Note that using a temp for swapping is not only easier to understand than the xor approach used here but also generally more efficient.

Comment: A protip here. Write an alternate version where you avoid fancy logic and run them both in a loop to see if they produce different results. That would give you a test case that you can show us.

Comment: The statement `for(i=0,j=i+1;i<n-1 && j<n;i=i+2,j=j+2)` suggests some errors. If this is an attempt to iterate `i` and `j` separately over the range of possible values, then it fails, as the loop iterates them together. If it is intended to iterate them together, then `i<n-1 && j<n` is redundant, as `i` and `j` are stepping synchronously, so they are both true or both false. It also does not seem to account for odd `n`.

Comment: i=0;
        j=i+1;
        while(i<n-1 || j<n){
            temp=a[i];
            a[i]=a[j];
            a[j]=temp;
            i=i+2;
            j=j+2;
        }      i have tried with this too.. but its not working:(

Comment: Keep in mind that you're swapping digits from left-to-right, so if you have an odd number of digits, e.g. "123", then you will get "213", as opposed to "132".  Is that your intent?

Comment: Very similar to the recent (2019-05-11) question [How to store multiple value of printf() in a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56092561/how-to-store-multiple-value-of-printf-in-a-variable).  You're excused for not finding it; the title does not give the game away.  Note that the referenced question has a strict 'even number of digits' requirement; it is not clear that you have exactly that requirement.  The code shown in the answer fails on big enough integers (some of those with 20 digits) — it silently overflows.

Comment: By the way, a simpler but equivalent way to write the for loop would be to use `for(i=0; (j=i+1)<n; i+=2)`.  Or, equivalently, `for(i=0; (j=i+1)<n; i=j+1)`

Answer (score 2):

```
a[i]^=a[j]^=a[i]^=a[j];
```

You're attempting to read and write both `a[i]` and `a[j]` in a single expression without a sequence point.  Doing so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Break up the expression into multiple lines.

```
a[i]^=a[j];
a[j]^=a[i];
a[i]^=a[j];
```

Comment: @priya One of the ways undefined behavior can manifest itself is by things appearing to work properly.  There's no guarantee that an unrelated change can suddenly seem to make things break.

Answer (score 0):

```
int n = strlen(a);
for ( int i=1; i < n; i+=2 ) {
   char c = a[i-1];
   a[i-1] = a[i];
   a[i] = c;
}
```